# Error Setting up Stack with react navigation using TypeScript and expo

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

loginStack.tsx
[image: error with code]

This error is popping up when I hover over the `screens` argument in the `createStackNavigator()` declaration. This is an example of what one of these `screens` looks like (they're all the same):

home.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global';

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <View style={globalStyles.container}>
            <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

I've run these commands to install the necessary libraries:

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
npm install @react-navigation/native
npm install @react-navigation/stack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to define your screens the old way, ie `react-navigation v4` way. From your imports, it is clear that you are using v5 or v6 of the library. To define your screens in v5 or v6, you can do the following,

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from '../screens/home';
import Login from '../screens/login';
import Registration from '../screens/registration';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={Registration} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Now in your `App.js` or your main entry point,

You can use this stack by wrapping it inside `NavigationContainer`

refer [React Navigation Official Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/) for detailed information.